# Updating a secondary form without lose focus of the main form

Tags: forms, delphi, focus, setfocus

I have this application in Delphi that has two forms one has a grid and another one has a map. Once you click in the grid the location of the vehicle is displayed on the map.

My problem is every time I update the location in the map this map form gets the focus, what do I need to do to call a procedure in the second form without lose the focus in the first one, avoiding this way the visual effects that windows have on change of focus.

I did some research and I find lots about creating and closing forms but noting about updating the form.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't show any code so we don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, simply calling code in the second form won't set focus to it. So there is something in particular that you are doing, or that a control on the second form is doing that is setting focus to that form.

I would look in the second form for things like SetFocus, Show, etc that may be being called when you update the map.

Comment: Thanks MikeD, one of the thirty part component I am using request focus, my temporary solution is to set visible to false before call it so it can get the focus and as soon as it come back I set it back to true.